# How can I make a drop down list in Excel 2013 based on several conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

**What I would like to achieve** is that sellers can choose the **STORE** in the ***blue cell*** (either with a drop down list or by hard-typing the STORE name) and, based on the selection on the *blue cell*, the available **POSITIONS** for that particular PRODUCT and that particular STORE are show in the ***green cell*** as a **drop down list**.

Let's say I have an Excel workbook, which contains a worksheet with this table with products data, which is automatically imported daily from our Nav server with this layout. It has 4 columns including PRODUCT CODE, DESCRIPTION, STORE IN WHICH IT CAN BE LOCATED and POSITION INSIDE DE STORE (please, check screenshot). It contains 1.5k rows and it changes dynamically, for example, new items are added or positions are exchanged.

[image: Products table screenshot]

As you can see, the same product (PRODUCT 2) can be located in several stores (STORES 1, 2 and 3), and it can be in several locations on each store (POSITIONS 2, 3, 1 and 4).

Now I need sellers to report which of these items they pick and from where, not only the STORE but its POSITION inside the store too. They do it with another worksheet inside the same Excel workbook. It looks more or less like this (please, check screenshot).

[image: Sellers report worksheet]

I know the drop down list is achieved via Data Validation but I can't figure out the formula for this. I have tried several approaches like:

- Array formula to return all POSITIONS in the same ROW, following this (Formula 2.): https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/. It is quite slow to calculate on the 1.5k items and, once done, I can't figure out how to make Data Validation to look for the 4 or 5 or 10 POSITIONS returned by the array formula, which also need to be filtered by STORE (please, check screenshot for the closest that I have been, array formula returning POSITIONS from column E).

[image: Array formula returning POSITIONS]

- Same formula as above directly on the Data Validation list box, which returns only the first POSITION found.
- VBA custom fucntions which are not allowed in the Data Validation box.

I feel comfortable with both Power Query and VBA, and forumla as well, and can adapt most of the code I see but I don't know why I just can't figure out how to achieve this, maybe it is only I am blocked or something but every path I start to follow ends up in a dead end.

Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this? It doesn't really seem that complicated but it is becoming impossible for me.

Thank you very much for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have finally done, just in case someone else is facing this situation.

1. Instead of a plain-text table for the POSITIONS, I created a PowerQuery importing that CSV. Named that worksheet _LOCATIONS.
2. Added a custom column (Column E) combining the PRODUCT and the STORE so I had something like a Unique Identificator, resulting something like this but in PowerQuery.

Combined column:

[image: Combined column]

3. Sorted column E and sub-sorted column D, so I make sure the list will always be ordered as I need, and saved the query.
4. Then, in worksheet REPORT, I entered this formula to create the drop down list in Data Validation in cell D2:

   `OFFSET(_LOCATIONS!$D$1,MATCH($A2&"-"&$C2,_LOCATIONS!$E:$E,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(_LOCATIONS!$E:$E,$A2&"-"&$C2))`

And I am able to choose from the available POSITIONS for the selected PRODUCT in the selected STORE.

Brief explanation:
I set the reference for the OFFSET function in the very first POSITION (D1), and then I move it the amount of rows detected by the MATCH function (which searches for the "PRODUCT 2-STORE 2" string in the newly created combined column) minus 1 (PoweryQuery table has headers) and 0 columns. This leaves me on the first occurrence of my string (but on the POSITIONS column). Then I make the offset as high as the amount of rows detected by the COUNTIF function (which counts all occurrences of my PRODUCT-STORE pair), returning an array of all the positions (column D) matching the PRODUCT-STORE pair.

Ask for formula in Spanish if you need it.